# Simulate skewed distribution

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, distribution-identification

I want to simulate a left-skewed distribution in R similar to
this one:

[image]

I can do it with `rbeta`

```
hist(print(rbeta(n = 1000, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 17)))
```

But then the x-values are between 0 and want, but I want them to be between 0 and 500 to resemble the actual data (which looks like the image I've posted).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Multiply by 500.

Comment: Please be sure that you really want to use a skewed distribution and not just a zero inflated one.

Comment: Your histogram is [right skewed, not left skewed](https://www.statology.org/left-skewed-vs-right-skewed/). Also, it doesn’t look like it’s bounded by 500.

Comment: @user2974951 The histogram shows there are values greater than 500, so your proposal won't do the job.